# How to create a plugin that replaces JPAPlugin and DBPlugin

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-1.x

I would like to create 2 plugins that will replace the JPAPlugin and DBPlugin of the play framework and prevent them from functioning.
I would like to replace the default behavior of these plugins by making 2 others plugins that will replace them.

How should I proceed ?
Do I just have to create these 2 plugins and give them a lower priority ? Or do I have to do something specific to be sure I'm replacing their default behavior by the behavior of my plugins ?

Thank you for your help !

PS: I'm using playframework 1.2.4

Comment: What's your use case for doing so?

Comment: I would like to implement my own JPAPlugin and DBPlugin to manage several databases. I know there is the multidb plugin and I also know the master branch of play manages several databases, but what I would like to do is a little bit different. I saw there is a plugin in play that can disable othre plugins so I'm wondering if using this plugin to disable the JPAPlugin and the DBPlugin would work

Answer (score 0):

A quick source search reveals that `play.test.Fixtures.resolveDependencies(Class<Model>, Map<String, String[]>)` has a hard-coded reference to the `JPAPlugin` class. So you'll need to fork the Play source to be able to not depend on the current `JPAPlugin` class.

Comment: But with code enhancement maybe I can replace all occurences of JPAPlugin by MyJPAPlugin ?

Comment: I mean maybe I can modify the JPAPlugin lass via byte code enhancement and replace its content by my class

Comment: Probably -- but modifying the Play code would be the easier and clearer solution.

Comment: I know, but I would like to write a plugin. So I'm trying to find to way to do what I want without modifying the source code. I think I will use bytecode enhancement to replace the content of the classes I need to modify